# Getting and splitting result from one column of MYSQL database to multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named as energymeter which have 3 columns named as Date, Name, Value.
I want a result of highest value of day- minimum value of day of each day in specified time period of individual parameter (Name) into 3 separate columns.

**Here is my table structure**

[image]

And i am getting result for single parameter as i wish using query

```sql
select Date(Date) as Date,
       Max(Value) - Min(Value) as Value , 
       Name 
from energy_meter.energy_meter 
WHERE Name ='Energy_Meters\[1\].Total_active_energy_kWh' 
  And DATE(Date) between '2022-10-01'  and '2022-10-13' 
group by DATE(Date)
```

and getting result as below

[image]

and i want result should look like below for all 3 parameters

[image]

Community help is needed.
Thanks

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: Remove the condition by `name` from WHERE but use conditional aggregation by this column. `.. MAX(CASE WHEN Name ='Energy_Meters\[1\].Total_active_energy_kWh' THEN Value END) .. AS Total_active_energy, ..`

Comment: MYSQL version is 8.0.

Comment: OK i am going to try and will inform u.

Comment: If so then enumeration in CTE then aggregation in outer query.